# Stop program from freezing while copying files

Tags: vb.net

I have made a game installer which copies some files from the installer to the game directory. However, when I click the button which runs the sub below, the program freezes until the action is complete.

```
Private Sub InstallGameFilesClicked(sender as object, e as eventargs) Handles InstallGmF.click
    My.computer.filesystem.copydirectory(environment.currentdirectory & "\res\gameFiles", installDir & "\res\")
End Sub
```

(installDir variable is a string set by the user previously in the program and determines the place where the game is going to be installed)

What I would like to have is for the program not to freeze when the button is clicked...

Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks, Rodit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way of executing tasks in the background is to use the `BackgroundWorker`. See [How to: Use a Background Worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1). The `BackgroundWorker` also allows you to give feedback to the UI in order to display a progress bar for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn how to use a background worker object.  It will run the copying in a different process than the one that the main part of your program uses and thus not cause it to freeze.  The background worker object can be found in the toolbox under components.

BackgroundWorker1

A word of warning, you have to know how to use it to get it to work correctly.  When it is done, it will return an event to the main part of your program and you should use that to signal the user that the copy process is complete, etc.  Just search for examples on how this works.